# duplicate declaration of method dismissviewdidfinish

Tags: iphone, ios

Have `two actionsheet buttons` and `one modalviewcontroller` on `mainviewcontroller` in application. Now for two `actionsheet` buttons and for `modalviewcontroller`, can i have multiple `dismissviewdidfinish method` for each

```
-(void)dismissViewDidFinish:(ModalViewController *)controller
{

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

-(void)dismissViewDidFinish:(Devanagari *)controller1;
{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion];

}

-(void)dismissViewDidFinish:(English *)controller2;
{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Cause if i add these three methods on mainviewcontroller  i get red warning message `duplicate declaration of method dismissviewdidfinish`.

Any ideas how to solve this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the same name for more than 1 method. Use a single `dismissViewDidFinish:(UIViewController *)viewController` method and then check to see which viewController finished:

```
- (void)dismissViewDidFinish:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    //check to see what kind of class viewController is
    //or use tags by setting the viewcontroller.view.tag when creating it
}
```

Comment: now it works fine but how can i check which viewcontroller finished. Because when i click on the done button to dismiss the viewcontroller on these three it works fine with this - (void)dismissViewDidFinish:(UIViewController *)viewController

Comment: actually in the protocol statement i have used the same for all three - (void)dismissViewDidFinish:(UIViewController *)viewController  as you suggested. So i think that will be ok too

Comment: You can do `[viewController isMemberOfClass:[English class]]` to check what class it is if you need to base your logic on this.